# Tkinter on Pydev Eclipse doesn't work

Tags: python, eclipse, tkinter

I tried to use Tkinter on eclipse, and it works for short codes such as this one:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
mainloop()
```

This code works on eclipse, but this one doesn't:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, HIDDEN, NORMAL

root = Tk()
root.title('Snap')

c = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)

shapes = []
circle = c.create_oval(35, 20, 365, 350, outline='black', fill='black',
                       state=HIDDEN)
shapes.append(circle)
circle = c.create_oval(35, 20, 365, 350, outline='red', fill='red',
                       state=HIDDEN)
shapes.append(circle)
circle = c.create_oval(35, 20, 365, 350, outline='green', fill='green',
                       state=HIDDEN)
shapes.append(circle)
circle = c.create_oval(35, 20, 365, 350, outline='blue', fill='blue',
                       state=NORMAL)
shapes.append(circle)
c.pack()
```

This code should make a window appear and have a blue circle on it, but I tried running it but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `root.mainloop()` at the end like so:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, HIDDEN, NORMAL

root = Tk()
root.title('Snap')

c = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
shapes = []
circle = c.create_oval(35, 20, 365, 350, outline='black', fill='black', state=HIDDEN)
shapes.append(circle)
circle = c.create_oval(35, 20, 365, 350, outline='red', fill='red', state=HIDDEN)
shapes.append(circle)
circle = c.create_oval(35, 20, 365, 350, outline='green', fill='green', state=HIDDEN)
shapes.append(circle)
circle = c.create_oval(35, 20, 365, 350, outline='blue', fill='blue', state=NORMAL)
shapes.append(circle)

c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

OR include `mainloop` in your import and run `mainloop()` instead of `root.mainloop()`

Comment: I once added it before, and it didn't work, but now when i tried it it worked for some reason.